# .Net Windows Application - using tableadapters and clearing dataset before page load

Tags: asp.net

I have a .Net windows forms application, and I need to load values into some combo boxes from tables in a database.  Now, the windows forms applications don't appear to work the same way as .Net web apps.  What I did, after reading the help information, was:

1. Create the data set in the "Data Sources" section of VS2008,
   specifying the table and columns I wanted returned
2. This set up as well as the dataset in my form three other objects, a
   "binding source" object, a table adapter and a tableadaptermanager.
3. In my combobox, I set the datasource property to the newly created
   bindingsource object, and the DisplayMember property to the column
   with the data that I wanted added.  So far, so good.

Now, time to test.  I run the app in debug mode - and the combobox gets populated with the values that I expected.  I select a value, a postback occurs, and then I get an error at pageload:  ConstraintException was unhandled.  Column 'name' is constrained to be unique. Value 'value I selected' is already present.

Ok, someone's not playing the cards I dealt them.  The "ClearBeforeFill" property on the table adapter is set to True, and in the page_load section I even explicitly put a line in calling the Clear() method on my data table.  What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by turning off "EnforceConstraints" on the underlying dataaset.  Somehow that seems "wrong" to me, but .Net didn't want to work as documentation said it should, particular the "ClearBeforeFill" property on the TableAdapter.